# Saving a pdf file opened in Adobe Reader by a process in c#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, save-as, adobe-reader

I am trying to open the file in Adobe Reader through "process" because Adobe reader can repair the corrupt file itself, but I need to “SaveAs” the file also from there at code level without manually saving it, is it possible in .net?

Code I am using :

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = file; 
p.Start(); 
//Code to Save As this file
p.Close(); 
corrupt = true; 
inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(file, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
```

Comment: Hi, Can this be done somehow using any opensource dll through .net only withoul third party API?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by poking the application with the AutomationAPI that is built into Windows.

TestStacks.White is an automation wrapper I've used in the past for automated UI testing, but it could also do what you require: https://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I have a similar problem, and unfortunately there is no UI option in Adobe Reader to simply save over the PDF. It requires you to choose a different folder than where the PDF was opened from. I have been looking for a way to either automate the "Save" or have the user "Save" over the current PDF, but Adobe Reader forces the user to manually navigate to the directory where the PDF resides.